# Using ROCm in Asus M1605Y for Whisper AI

Tags: dependencies

I recently bought an Asus vivobook M1605Y.
I installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 because according to this page https://rocm.docs.amd.com/en/latest/release/gpu_os_support.html it is compatible with ROCm.
When I try to install it, this is the error I get:

```
sudo apt install rocm-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rocm-dkms : Depends: rocm-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: rock-dkms but it is not installable
```

Could anyone help me understand what this means?

Does it mean my Asus is not compatible with ROCm and therefore I can't use the GPU with Whisper?

Thank you in advance,
Ayar